# React-query causes the whole React tree to unmount on response error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

As it is said here [React docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#new-behavior-for-uncaught-errors), on **uncaught** errors the whole tree will unmount.

**Query 1**:

```
const { data: post } = useQuery<PostResponseDto, AxiosError>(
  ['fetch-post', params],
  () => fetchPost(params!.postId),
  {
    refetchOnMount: true,
    onError: (err) => {
      // do something with the error
    },
  },
);
```

**Query 2**:

```
const {
  data: postCommentsGroups,
  fetchNextPage,
  isFetchingNextPage,
  hasNextPage,
  refetch,
} = useInfiniteQuery<PostCommentsResponseDto, AxiosError>(
  ['fetch-post-comments', params],
  ({ pageParam = 0 }) => fetchPostComments(params!.postId, pageParam),
  {
    refetchOnMount: true,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      if (!lastPage.data.nextPage) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return lastPage.data.nextPage;
      }
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      // do something with the error
    },
  },
);
```

**Fetch functions**:

```
export const fetchPost = async (webId: string) => {
  const response = await axiosInstance.get(`${API_URL}/post/${webId}`);
  return response.data;
};

export const fetchPostComments = async (webId: string, page: number) => {
  const response = await axiosInstance.get(
    `${API_URL}/post/${webId}/comments?page=${page}&limit=${COMMENTS_LIMIT}`,
  );
  return response.data;
};
```

**The problem**: When these queries result in status code !== 200, uncaught errors appear in the console (see below) and the whole React tree unmounts. This definitely is not the behavior I want. E.g. on both of these queries I get 404 if `postId` is incorrect and when this happens I want to do certain actions in `onError` callback (show some info to the user), but this impossible due to the uncaught errors by react-query and React unmounting the whole tree.

[image]
This is one of the few uncaught errors (`AxiosError`s).

**Why is this happening?**

P.S.: I don't think this happens with `useMutate()` hook.

P.P.S: I am using global `ErrorBoundary` but that is irrelevant for this problem. I want to manipulate the DOM in that specific component in which queries are being made/errored.

Comment: React-query should catch all the errors. Could you reproduce it on CodeSandbox or somewhere?

Comment: Do you have `useErrorBoundary: true` in your react query client?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Yes, for some reason I added that proeprty at query client init. Thank you.

Comment: The AxiosError being logged is just a development feature of the react-query built in logger. The answer lies in the `Uncaught` error of useBaseQuery line 97. Obviously I can't expand your screenshot which is why screenshots are bad. Please show what this error is or reproduce in a codesandbox example, because this behaviour shouldn't happen.